# Compressing read data (converting fastq to fastq.gz) on Windows

Tags: fasta, fastq

I downloaded some of my data in fastq format instead of fastq.gz. I want to upload my data on a server now.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert my fastq files to fastq.gz on windows (I read some stuff about python, but I'm not quite sure) before uploading them on the server, since it takes a lot of time uploading the fastq files.

Comment: How about downloading onto the server directly? How did you download, as when it is from NCBI it will be faster to just redownload and gzip-compress on the fly.

Answer (score 7):

`7zip` is file archiver capable of running `gzip`-style compression, and runs on Windows: https://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 2):

If your Windows 10 build number is 17063 or later, you can use `tar` command to compress file in Windows PowerShell:

```
tar -vczf output.fq.gz input.fastq
```

The `-z` flag means to compress archive with gzip.

Answer (score -1):

Bioinformatics is 99% done in [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) environments, and trying to come up with Windows solutions is unnecessary effort. The Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL2) provides you with a native Linux distribution within Windows that easily allow you to do any Unix-ish thing such as running gzip. It is straight-forward to install, see its online documentation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could be a little less condescending especially given how late your answer is.